# How do I change the value of a single variable in R to a range, where that range is dependent on the value of the original variable?

Tags: r, statistics, subset, bioinformatics, data-analysis

So I have data on CpG sites, and a column which defines their chromosomal position (e.g. 10000).

How would I change these values such that I can attain values in a range dependent on that original value. For example 10000 would be +/- 500 (9500 - 10500).

I'm going to be using the same parameters for each variable regardless of it's value.

I have tried

```
df$upstream <- df$value - 500
df$downstream <- df$value + 500
```

Which returns the upper and lower values I need, but how do I get this 'range' into a single column (e.g. such that I can search for it in genomebrowser)?

Comment: Sounds like you would need to create lower and upper bound columns (ranges) based on a formula of the fixed value.  E.g. `df$lower <- 0.9 * df$value`, `df$upper <- 1.1 * df$value`.

Comment: I'm very unclear about your input and your expected output. Do you want to simulate random values from that range? Do you want to produce the string `"+/- 500 (9500 - 10500)"`? Do you want to add columns for the upper and lower bounds? Do you want a `list` column containing every integer value in the range? Is it always a +/- 500 range, or is there some logic for determining the range? What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: MFerris99, welcome to Stack Overflow. I see your question received a downvote, but I think if you can update it in response to Gregor Thomas it will be upvoted and perhaps more importantly, get you clear, helpful answers.

Comment: @GregorThomas Apologies, I am new to R and programming generally. I tried what has been suggested 'df$upstream <- df$position -500' 'df$downstream <- df$position + 500' and returned the values I wanted. How would I go about containing the separate columns into a list?

Comment: I don't know what `genomebrowser` is, but I'd be surprised if it works with list columns? Can you be more specific about what output you actually want? It could be a `list`-class column that contains vectors in each row with the upper and lower bounds---but don't ask for that just because I suggest it. It could be a `character` class column with the string `"+/- 500 (9500 - 10500)"`, or a simpler string like `"9500 - 10500"`, or ... I don't know. Please tell us exactly what you want, and we can help you get there.

Comment: I think it is the `list`-class column that I need. Because I need to then convert it into a BED file in order to search for multiple regions in genomebrowser. Or maybe I could just transfer the columns (the 'upstream' and 'downstream') over to this file format? Need to look into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked with such dataset during and on my side, to perform this, I use to create new columns on my dataset using (as mentioned in the comment):

```
df$upstream = df$position - 500
df$downstream = df$position + 500
```

Hope it helped

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: Ok, you can validate the answer if you think it will work for some other people ;)